# rendering iscroll on android / phonegap project

Tags: android, iscroll

Does anyone know of any android app which uses iscroll. I would like to test it on my device. Reason being that my current phonegap/android project does not work with iscroll4....

I will post details of the same later....but just want to see if iscroll atall works on android...I have my doubts...

Tried all the approaches of calling iscroll but simply does not work..

here is the code for requirejs:

```
define(['jquery','domready',
       function($,domReady){
       var menu_iscroll;

       function loaded() {
               alert("inside loaded for iscroll:dom under hmenu is");   
           alert($('#hmenu').html());
           if ($('#hmenu').length){
           alert('setting iscroll');
           menu_iscroll = new iScroll('hmenu');}
       };

       document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

       domReady(function() {
           alert("entered domready for creating iscroll");  
               loaded();
       });

       return menu_iscroll;
       });
```

and here is code for main.js:

```
require.config({
    paths:{ 
    jquery:'vendor/jquery/jquery.min',
    'jquery.mobile':'vendor/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min',
    'jquery.mobile-config':'jqm-config',
    underscore:'vendor/underscore/underscore-min',
    backbone:'vendor/backbone/backbone-min',
    handlebars:'vendor/handlebars/handlebars',
    text:'vendor/text/text',
    bootstrap:'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min',
    iscroll:'vendor/iscroll/dist/iscroll-min',
    domready:'vendor/domReady'
    },

    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            //These script dependencies should be loaded before loading backbone.js
            deps: ['jquery','underscore'],
            //Once loaded, use the global 'Backbone' as the module value.
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },

        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },

    'handlebars' : {
            exports : "Handlebars"
        },

    'iscroll' : {
            exports : "iScroll"
        },


    'jquery.mobile-config': {
            deps: ['jquery']
    },  

    'jquery-mobile': {
        deps:['jquery','jquery.mobile-config'],
    },

    },

    waitSeconds:10,
});


require(['jquery','views/menuscroll','index'],function($,scrollView){         
    new scrollView;  

});
```

and inside scrollview:

```
define(['jquery','domready','iscroll','test'],
       function($,domReady,iScroll,testView){
       new testView; //this is where all the rendering of the DOM occurs...
       var menu_iscroll;

       function loaded() {
               alert("inside loaded for iscroll:dom under hmenu is");   
           alert($('#hmenu').html());
           if ($('#hmenu').length){
           alert('setting iscroll');
           menu_iscroll = new iScroll('hmenu');}
       };

       document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

       domReady(function() {
           alert("entered domready for creating iscroll");  
               loaded();
       });

       return menu_iscroll;
       });
```

I am now pretty confident after debugging that with phonegap/iscroll/requirejs on android platform that the much marketed iscroll module fails to render on android....it simply does not work...

Comment: In order to confirm this performed a simple experiment which confirms my doubts: Copied the html file from the famous example: http://jonathanstark.com/labs/iscroll/examples/horizontal-scroll/ and tried to render it on android 2.3.5 phone with phonegap....THE SCROLLING DOES NOT WORK! SO FOR EVERYONE WHO IS CURRENTLY WORKING WITH PHONEGAP AND WANT A HORIZONTAL SCROLL PROBABLY iscroll is NOT THE WAY...

Comment: Could you please post your `HTML` & `CSS` code too? Because `iScroll` is mostly depend on `HTML` and `CSS` too.